# showing multipe <li> as multi-row with 1px border between cells, without altering HTML markup

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create something similar to the below:

[image]

The html markup is basically one `<ul>` and 6 `<li>`.  The issue is that if you define 'border' of 1px throughout, it would end up with a 2px border.  Is there any way to 'collapse' the border?  I would like it such that I can easily decide if I want 3 per row, 4 per row, etc.  Currently, that is done by using for example `width: 33.33333%` to show 3, and `display: inline-block`.

I wouldn't like to actually group each row by HTML markup, where say each row would be in a physical `<ul>`. I've tried the `margin-left: -1px` technique, however the problem is that the whole row would be shifted by say `3px` to the left.

Is there any possible solution to this by just using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
li:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't remove the white border.  Basically, I only want the border on the inside of the cells.  No outer border.  It would be better to make it say red, so that you can see where the border is as white-on-white doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here's a possible answer (keeping the  as one):

```
#mylist li {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 33.333%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruhcdd0s/1/

Version with javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/hpymjrvd/

Hope it helps! :)

**EDIT:** fiddle updated! And javascript version added

Comment: Similarly, this is 'working' because the width is set as 33%. This leaves enough room for margins / paddings to work.  However, if you change it to a more exact number, say 25% (4 per row), it doesn't work.

Comment: @KarlCassar Then you probably gonna need some Javascript. I've update the fiddle in the answer and added the one with the javascript in it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go the flex way: http://jsfiddle.net/vnwog3o6/

If you can't use `display: flex` then this is a more old browser friendly way: http://jsfiddle.net/vnwog3o6/3/

Fiddle looking more like what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/vnwog3o6/2/

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    margin: 0;

    list-style: none;
}

li {
    width: 33.33%;

    background-color: red;
    border-right: 1px solid green;
}

li:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: 0;
}

li:nth-child(n+4) {
    border-top: 1px solid green;
}
```

Then if you wanted to change it from 3 items to 4 items you change `width: 25%`, `3n` to `4n` and `n+4` to `n+5`

`li:nth-child(3n)` means every 3rd item remove the right border
`li:nth-child(3n)` means every item (4th and above) add a top border

Comment: Unfortunately flex is not fully supported by all major browsers, as it's fully implemented from IE11 onwards.

Comment: It works in IE10+. You can use a float method way which would accomplish the same thing if you want me to knock that up quickly

Comment: @KarlCassar i've added the float way for you